# Javascript Filter Function Not Allowing Removal of Newline Characters

Tags: javascript, string, newline, strip

I'm new to Javascript, and don't understand why the output of the following two approaches produce different results.

In the first example (`method 1`), I'm starting with an empty string then looping through every word of a sample text and checking if it's an alphanumeric sequence (i.e. word.trim() !== emptyString).

In the second example (`method 2`), I'm *trying* to use the `filter` function to do the same thing, by removing any words that are non-alphanumeric (line breaks, spaces, tabs, etc.) and then using the `join` command to "glue" everything back together.

Below is my approach:

```js
// Sample Text
// Note the newline characters
let text =
    "quoth that of all the kings of earth \n" +
    "of men he was mildest and most beloved \n" +
    "to his kin the kindest keenest for praise";

// Method 1
let filtered = "";
for (let word of text.split(" ")){
    if(word.trim() !== ""){
        filtered += word.trim() + " "; // word padding via concatenation
    }
}
console.log(filtered, '\n'); // ----------- Output One

// Method 2 - using filter function
let output = text.split(" ").filter(function(word){
    return word.trim() !== "" ? word : "";
}).join(" ");  // word padding via join() method
console.log(output, '\n'); // ----------- Output Two
```

The output of the first method is this:

```
quoth that of all the kings of earth of men he was mildest and most beloved to his kin the kindest keenest for praise
```

The output of the second method is this:

```
quoth that of all the kings of earth 
of men he was mildest and most beloved 
to his kin the kindest keenest for praise
```

Each approach is using the same `word.trim() !== ""` logic to filter, but the second seems to not correctly filter out newline characters?

As a sanity check, I tried the second approach to remove the first word `quoth` using the same logical approach as such:

```
// Sanity Check
let outputTwo = text.split(" ").filter(function(word){
    return word !== "quoth" ? word : "";
}).join(" ");
console.log(outputTwo);
```

The output is as follows:

```
that of all the kings of earth 
of men he was mildest and most beloved 
to his kin the kindest keenest for praise
```

The first word `quoth` was removed, as expected.

I don't understand why the newline characters aren't being removed using the second method.

**Note:** My question is NOT "how to remove newline characters in javascript". I'm aware this might not be the most efficient way to approach this.

**Update**
Thank you `@Robin Zigmond` for pointing out my silly logic. It completely makes sense that the string `earth \nof men` would result in `[earth, \nof, men]` when using the `split()` function.

Also, I can say that the following code, using the `map` function as suggested produces the desired result:

```
// Method 3
let outputThree = text.split(" ").map(
    word => word.trim() !== "" ? word.trim() : ""
).join(" ");
console.log(outputThree, '\n');
```

While similar in logic, note the use of the `word.trim()` approach for resulting concatenation. That clearly changes a string such as `\nof` into `of`.

HOWEVER, when adapting the `method 2` from above to incorporate the `word.trim()` approach, it still produces the text containing the newlines. Here:

```
// Method 2.1 - using filter function
let output = text.split(" ").filter(function(word){
    return word.trim() !== "" ? word.trim() : "";
}).join(" ");  // word padding via join() method
console.log(output, '\n'); // ----------- Output Two.1
```

It's same logic is being used in each method now (I think?) by way of this line;

```
word.trim() !== "" ? word.trim() : "";
```

But the approach using `filter` still doesn't seem to pick up the newline character.

**Update**
Thank you @NikosM —knowing the `filter()` function returns a `boolean` clears everything up. It's *detecting* the newline, just not performing any action beyond that.

Comment: Did you forget to attach code for Method 2.

Comment: @bestinamir OP already has already included method two, just the end of the code snippet.

Comment: `.filter` method should return a boolean not a string, even though empty. it is treated as true and avoids the filter test

Comment: @NikosM. Thank you! That clears things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your string is the following, if one manually does the concatenations:

```
let text =
"quoth that of all the kings of earth \nof men he was mildest and most beloved \nto his kin the kindest keenest for praise";
```

Note that the newline characters are directly "next to" the following word, with no space inbetween. So when you call `split(" ")` on the strong, you end up with eg. `"\nof"` as entries in the array.

This matters because your two methods don't actually do the same thing. The first adds the result of calling `.trim()` on each "word", whereas the second simply adds the "word" unchanged, provided it doesn't trim down to the empty string. `"\nof"` doesn't do the latter, so you end up with that in the output string, as you are seeing. Whereas in the first code sample, you add `"\nof".trim()`, that is `"of"`.

Note that you can use the `map` method to apply an operation, such as `.trim` here, to each element of the array - either before or after the filter.

Comment: First, I agree the `map` method is much more concise. I wasn't aware of that! Please see the update to my answer. There still seems to be an issue even when I concatenate as `word.trim()` in that newlines still don't seem to be removed.

Comment: I didn't say you should use `map` *instead of* `filter`.`map` simply applies a function to each element of the list, and can't "skip over" any of them. The "correct" solution along these lines would be `text.split(" ").map(word => word.trim()).filter(word => word !== "").join(" ")` (although that `filter` shouldn't actually be needed for this particular text)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to followup. That makes sense—I was thinking `map` and `filter` seemed oddly similar.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `String.replace` it will be much more efficient. And in the end, you want just to replace newline character with space...

```js
// Sample Text
// Note the newline characters
let text =
    "quoth that of all the kings of earth \n" +
    "of men he was mildest and most beloved \n" +
    "to his kin the kindest keenest for praise";

// Method 1
let filtered = text.replace(/\n/, ' ');
console.log(filtered, '\n'); // ----------- Output One
```

Comment: Please read the *Note* section of the question. This was not a question about efficiency or "how to remove a newline in javascript"